# $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$ is convergent for $n>0$

Tags: improper-integrals

I have something to ask regarding convergence of gamma function. I have done the proof as below. Please tell me if it is correct.

> **$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$ is convergent for $n>0$**

***Proof:*** For $n\in(0,1],~\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$ is convergent since $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx=\int_0^1 e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx+\int_1^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx\le\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx+\int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx.$

On the other hand, $\int e^{-x}x^{(n+1)-1}dx=-x^n.e^{-x}+n\int e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx\cdots(1)$

Since, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^n.e^{-x}=0,$ by successive application of $(1)$ $n$ can be put in $(0,1],$ whence the result follows.

Comment: The proof is flawed.  For $x>1$, $x^{n-1} \not \le 1$ when $n>1$

Comment: Instead of integrating by parts, you can pick $a(n) \in (0,1),c(n)$ such that $x^{n-1} < c(n) e^{a(n) x}$ for $x > 1$

Answer (score 2):

The proof in the OP fails when $n>1$ since for $x>1$, $x^{n-1}>1$ or $n>1$.

But we can assert that $e^x\ge \frac{x^{\lfloor n\rfloor+1}}{(\lfloor n\rfloor +1)!}$ for $x \ge 1$.  So, for $L\ge1$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_1^L e^{-x}x^{n-1}\,dx\right|&\le \left(\lfloor n\rfloor+1\right) ! \int_1^L x^{n-\lfloor n\rfloor -2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\left(\lfloor n\rfloor+1\right) !}{\left(n-\lfloor n\rfloor-1\right) }\left(L^{\left(n-\lfloor n\rfloor-1\right) }-1\right)
\end{align}$$

Since $n-\lfloor n\rfloor -1<0$, $\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(\lfloor n\rfloor+1\right) !}{\left(n-\lfloor n\rfloor-1\right) }\left(L^{\left(n-\lfloor n\rfloor-1\right) }-1\right)
\right)=\frac{\left(\lfloor n\rfloor+1\right) !}{1-\left(n-\lfloor n\rfloor\right) }$, and the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ converges.  And we are done!